# Capture SwiftUI View as Movie? Access drawingGroup() MTKView?

Tags: view, swiftui, metal, metalkit

The title says it all.

Is there a way to render a SwiftUI View to a moviefile in background?
An ideal solution would be, that the View being captured is not even displayed on screen.

I read about some answers on how to capture a MTKView and thought about accessing the underlaying view of drawingGroup(). Despite a lot of research I couldn't find any way to access it.

On the other hand, there is the inelegant way to render and capture the view as an UIView.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it will be possible, it will brake the security rules ... and radar should be filled.

Comment: @user3441734 What do you mean with 'radar should be filled'?

Comment: I mean, that it will be some bug in iOS. Check the apple's security policy for further details.